# Is $y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1t+z_t$ stationary?

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, stochastic-processes, stationarity

> Let the model $$y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1t+z_t\qquad t=1,2,\dots$$
>   $$z_t=\epsilon_t+\theta\epsilon_{t-1}$$ where $\epsilon_t$ is White
>   noise with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$ and
>   $\beta_0,\beta_1,\theta$ constants.
>
> a) Is $y_t$ stationary?
>
> b) Is $(1-B)y_t$ stationary? (where $B$ is a lag operator)

This model can be written as
$$y_t=\delta_t+\epsilon_t+\theta\epsilon_{t-1}$$

a) It is not a stationary process, this process have trend and clearly this have no constant mean, because $E[y_t]$ varies according to $t$.

b) $$(1-B)y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1t+\epsilon_t+\theta\epsilon_{t-1}-\beta_0-\beta_1(t-1)+\epsilon_{t-1}-\theta\epsilon_{t-2}$$
$$=\beta_1+\epsilon_t+\epsilon_{t-1}(\theta-1)+\theta\epsilon_{t-2}$$
$$=\beta_1+\epsilon_t[1+B(\theta-1)-\theta B^2]$$

$$B=\frac{(1-\theta)\pm \sqrt{(\theta-1)^2+4\theta}}{2}$$

The roots are $1$ and $-\theta$, so this process is not stationary?

I have other doubts too:

1) The process $y_t$ is a $MA(1)$ with non-zero mean?

2) When I look the roots of polynomial, both roots need to be $>1$ in modulus or just one is enough?

Comment: What is the definition of $B$ in _"b) Is $x_t=(1−B)y_t$ stationary?"_

Comment: B is the backshift operator.  B X_t =X_(t-1).  First of all y_t is nonstationary.  It has a linear trend so the mean changes over time. Why did you ask and answer that question in your Post?

Comment: You are confusing people by changing x_t to y_t in your notation.

Comment: I am confused all you did was reexpress y_t.  It is difficult see what point you are trying to make. y_t being nonstationary is settled.

Comment: y_t is not a moving average process. It has a moving average component.

Comment: X_t removes the linear trend. It doesn't make sense to solve for B.  B is an operator.

Comment: The second line in the determination of x_t is almost right but the theta that multiplies e_(t-2) should have a minus sign. in any event x_t is a moving average process with mean beta_1. It could be stationary according to Box and Jenkins if theta satisfies the condition of invertibility.

Comment: Actually the invertibility condition for an MA process is only necessary for the process to have an infinite autoregressive representation. An MA(q) process is second order stationary since  as in your example x_t has a constant mean and a constant finite variance and the autocovariance function only depends on the number the number of lags k between x_t and x_(t-k) and not on t.  For the MA(q) process beyond lag q the the autocovariance is 0. For finite autoregressive processes there is a stationarity condition that must be satisfied for the  process to be stable.

Comment: The condition involves the roots of the characteristic polynomial . In the Case of the AR(1) process this means that the autoregressive parameter p must satisfy |p|<1.

Comment: Even as edited y_t is not a moving average process and is nonstationary because  the mean changes with time because of the linear trend. The series  x_t  is a MA(2) process and is second order stationary since q=2 and the variance is constant and finite.

Comment: The conditions related to the characteristic polynomial apply to finite AR processes but not finite MA processes.  Note that there are several types of stationarity, wide sense,, second order etc.  Check out Wikipedia for a discussion of this.  On this site there are examples that show second order stationarity does not imply strict stationarity.  The exception is for Gaussian processes i.e. when the white noise term in your example is normally distributed.  I explain that here in an answer to a question from several years back.

Comment: @MichaelChernick How I know if a process is a Moving Average process or just have a Moving Average Component? If instead of trend component I just have a constant that don't changes over time, it would be a non-zero mean Moving Average process right?

Comment: @Roland I don't think so. y_t has a linear trend component which is why it is nonstationary..  Added to that trend is a moving average process. That is why I say it has a moving average component.

Answer (score 2):

1) No, the series $\boldsymbol{Y} \equiv \{ Y_t | t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is not stationary.  The trend term in $t$ means that a shift in the time index will yield a different distribution.

2) Let $Z_t \equiv (1-B) Y_t$ be the first-difference of the original series and let $\boldsymbol{Z} \equiv \{ Z_t | t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ be the series of first-differences.  As you have already derived (your derivation has errors but the result is correct), this time-series is an MA($2$) process with coefficients $\theta_1 = \theta - 1$ and $\theta_2 = -\theta$ and fixed mean $\mathbb{E}(Z_t) = \beta_1$ .  It has stationary distribution:

$$Z_t \sim \text{N} \Big( \beta_1, 2 (\theta^2 - \theta + 1) \sigma^2 \Big) .$$